# How to open all fonts at once?

Tags: import, text-object

I want to make all of the files in the windows/font/ folder open all at once in blender instead of needing to add each one in the folder individually.
I need all of the fonts to be pre loaded or open so they display in this menu here:
[image: font setting for text object]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use python.

```
from bpy import ops
from glob import glob
from os import chdir, path

directory = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts"

chdir(directory)
for file in glob("*.ttf") + glob("*.otf"):
    ops.font.open(filepath = path.join(directory, file), relative_path=False)
```

Replace the `directory` variable with the folder path, which contains your font files. Escape \ with \.

Paste the script in the text editor and press *Run Script*.

Comment: That worked 100% thank you! Would you also happen to know how to add all fonts in blender to the create font list node automatically? [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bdpjwieekqjsp9k/blender_2016-12-14_18-24-45.png]

Comment: Couple of suggestions can set the font path in user preferences files `context.user_preferences.filepaths.font_directory`, this can be used for `directory`.   Using `os.path.join(directory, file)`  in `font.open(..)`  will make the script cross platform.

Comment: @Nicholas Ask a new question. batFINGERThanks for the correction. I updated the post.

Comment: IMO font.open should be multi file, (letting you select multiple or all with "a").  Using your code could quickly make an override of operator that uses the selected files list.

Comment: I had the same problem in Blender 3.6. I thought the script didn't work cuz it gave an error, but I just forgot to use double backslashes separating folder names in the file path (Windows file browser only uses single backslashes, so you gotta fix the path manually if you decide to copy it). With that in mind, I can confirm the script still works for the newest versions of Blender.

Comment: @michalpe This is python code. In Python the ```\``` character is a special character in strings and introduces an escape sequence followed by other coded characters. Typing ```"\\"``` in code is the command for a single backslash.