# Text script issue

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I'm needing to generate a set of different texts each in their own font so that I can see which one would look best, something like this (have a whole bunch of fonts do do this with).

[image: Wanted]

I created a short test script, which when ran it ends up looking like this.

[image]

Here's the script, each individual text works when ran alone, but they won't work if all texts are generated.  Any ideas why it won't work?  Probably something simple I'm overlooking.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
txt = bpy.data.objects['Text']
txt.data.body = 'Brush Script'
fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load('/Library/Fonts/Brush Script.ttf')
txt.data.font = fnt

bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, 1, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
txt1 = bpy.data.objects['Text']
txt1.data.body = 'Chalkboard'
fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load('/Library/Fonts/Chalkboard.ttc')
txt1.data.font = fnt

bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, 2, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
txt2 = bpy.data.objects['Text']
txt2.data.body = 'Chalkduster'
fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load('/Library/Fonts/Chalkduster.ttf')
xt2.data.font = fnt
```

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69255/how-to-open-all-fonts-at-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example of all fonts in a directory. I'm sure someone else can improve the coding for optimization.

```
import bpy
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = 'G:\\Blender Working folders\\Fonts'  # your font directory

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
count = 0
for f in onlyfiles:
    bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, count, 0))
    txt = bpy.context.active_object
    txt.data.body = f
    fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load(join(mypath, f))
    txt.data.font = fnt
    count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked with a few changes, as I'm using a mac

Comment: import bpy
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = '/Library/Fonts/'  # your font directory

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
count = 0
print (onlyfiles)

for f in onlyfiles:
    if f.endswith('.ttf') or f.endswith('.TTF') or f.endswith('.otf'):
        bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, count, 0))
        txt = bpy.context.active_object
        txt.data.body = f
        fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load(join(mypath, f))
        txt.data.font = fnt
    count += 1